# How to define an inline function according to another inline function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, inline

Suppose that I have a vector of variables that I have created in this way:

```
A = sym('A%d',[1 , 3]);
```

And also an inline function which is a function of A:

```
f = inline(A(1)^2 + A(2)^3 - 10*A(3) , 'A');
```

Now, the question is how to define another function like `g` that has the following form:
`g = f*10` or any other types of functions that depends on `f`.

thanks in advance

Comment: Any reason to use the deprecated `inline`? Use anonymous functions instead!

Comment: how should I do that? could you please explain?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation about anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html?s_tid=doc_12b)? First try to redefine `f` as a anonymous function.

Comment: f=@(x) (x+1); g(x)=@(x) (x^2); fg=@(x) g(f(x));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Daniel, you should use [anonymous functions](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). In the documentation to `inline`, Mathworks warns that this will be removed in a future release, and tells you to use anonymous functions.

The syntax of anonymous functions is very easy:

```
f =  @(A) A(1)^2 + A(2)^3 - 10*A(3)
```

with `@(A)`, you define that you want one input variable, and name it `A`. If you have two inputs, `A` and `B`, then write `@(A,B)`. But caution: these names `A` and `B` are only internal names inside your anonymous function. The following two functions are 100% identical:

```
f1 = @(x) 10*x
f2 = @(A) 10*A
```

You can call these anonymous functions like normal functions, e.g.

```
f([1, 2, 3])
f(x)
```

If you want to create a function `g = 10*f`, then you define this function as

```
g = @(A) 10*f(A)
```

Here's a small demonstration:

```
A = sym('A%d',[1 , 3]);
f =  @(x) x(1)^2 + x(2)^3 - 10*x(3)
g = @(x) 10*f(x)

g(A) 
ans = 
    10*A1^2 + 10*A2^3 - 100*A3
```